# Node.js server stops working when database is changed from v2.6 to 3.0?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mlab, modulus.io

I have a node.js server and I was using a Mongodb v2.6. Today I have upgraded that to Mongodb v3.0 and the app has stopped responding but it still responds to v2.6. Any ideas on how to fix this? Mongolab will be upgrading all databases to v3.0.

I have also tried implementing it at modulus.io without any results. I use Mongoose with my node.js app.

Comment: When will Mongolab be upgrading their databases? If this timescale is not good for you, either contact their support to see if you can stay on the old version for a period of time, or find a provider who can offer the old version. It does not seem to be sensible to me to be rushed into a major version upgrade that you are not prepared for.

Comment: (I appreciate that this issue is urgent to you, but I try to discourage requests for urgency in questions, since all questions here are of equal importance, and the urgency won't be of interest to readers in the future anyway).

Comment: For others that find this thread, here's a link to our maintenance doc: http://docs.mongolab.com/20150930-maintenance-event/. Please be sure to update your driver to 3.0-compatible versions and if you'd like to avoid this window, you can upgrade to any for-pay plan running 2.6 prior to the maintenance window. If you have any questions, reach out to us at support@mongolab.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the version of Mongoose you included in package.json isn't shared, I am hoping that needs an update too.

Here's the article where Mongoose 4.0 is said to be supporting Mongo 3.0: [https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/introducing-version-40-mongoose-nodejs-odm](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/wiki/4.0-Release-Notes)

Also, if you are upgrading Mongoose to 4.0, check the backwards incompatible changes and new features sections in their Release Notes.
https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/wiki/4.0-Release-Notes

Comment: Ooops Yeah.. I completely forgot about that.